# Mongoose how to insert element on existing objects (MongoDB and Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my model, I have something like this:

```
subjects: {
    Mathematics: {
      questionsanswered: [
        "x+2=3, solve for x please",
        "How do you write an expression that represents all quadrantal angles?"
      ],
      questionsasked: [
        "how to convert sin to cos?",
        "factor the trinomial: 3x^2+7x+2"
      ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, there're a lot of sub-elements and I'm totally beginner with Mongoose and Node.js, I'm trying to add another question(string) in the `questionsanswered` array field. I looked up on the documentation and tried

```
userModel.update({username: username},{$pushAll: { subjects:{Mathematics:{questionsasked:['what is the definition of calculus']}}}},{upsert:true},function(err){
                if(err){
                        console.debug(err);
                }else{
                        console.debug("Successfully added");
                }
        });
```

But it says 'Modifier $pushAll allowed for arrays only', does anyone know how to insert another element in the `questionsanswered` array? Thanks a lot ahead!

Comment: Try `$pushAll: {"subjects.Mathematics.questionsasked": "what is the definition of calculus"}`

Comment: it still says the same thing :S

Comment: Nvm, I got it working with {"subjects.Mathematics.questionsasked": ["what is the definition of calculus"]}

Just had to add the ' [ ] '

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`$pushAll` is deprecated now.

To add one element to an existing array just use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/):

```
userModel.update({ username }, { $push: {
  'subjects.Mathematics.questionsasked': 'value'
}});
```

To add element if not present use [`addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/):

```
userModel.update({ username }, { $addToSet: {
  'subjects.Mathematics.questionsasked': 'unique value'
}});
```

To add multiple elements use [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each):

```
userModel.update({ username }, { $push: {
  'subjects.Mathematics.questionsasked': { $each: ['value1', 'value2'] }
}});
```